Rotate icon in MudBlazor
I am using blazor .net 8 with MudBlazor for UI. I have Button with Start/End icon and i want to Rotate that icon How Can i?
 <MudButton Color="Color.Info" OnClick="@(e => { Share("G"); })" EndIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.IosShare">
     Share
 </MudButton>

This is my Button with Icon how can i rotate icon to 45 degree or 90 degree....
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You can use the IconClass property to set your own class for the icon.
As for the CSS you can use transform property.
<style>
    .rotate-icon-45{
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    .rotate-icon-90{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
</style>
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.IosShare" Color="Color.Primary">ShareNormal</MudButton>
<MudButton IconClass="rotate-icon-45" Variant="Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.IosShare" Color="Color.Primary">Share45</MudButton>
<MudButton IconClass="rotate-icon-90" Variant="Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.IosShare" Color="Color.Primary">Share90</MudButton>

Demo  MudBlazor snippet
